# Where is the Admin Menu links stored in Joomla & WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, joomla, hyperlink

Hi I wanted to know where are the Admin Menu links stored in Joomla & WordPress database?

Let me explain....

I am running Joomla and WordPress both and I wanted to integrate the back-end-menus into each other. Some Joomla Admin Menu links into WordPress back-end and similarly some WordPress Menu Links into Joomla Backend Menu.

For the same I was trying to figure out as to where can I find these links and how can I cal them?

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? are you talking about example.com/wordpress/wp-admin? And can you explain what you mean by "cross-link".

Comment: Sorry for the short question. I edited it. Please go through it again. Basically I want to create some shortcut links. For example while I am working in Joomla, suddenly I need to work on some page in WordPress I should have a link in Joomla which should take me to the Words Page Options panel. likewise some Joomla links into wordPress. For this purpose I wanted to know as to where does these applications store them so that i can call them from that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about single login this isn't something that is easily accomplished. You could always try a plugin like [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog/6659?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo5OiJ3b3JkcHJlc3MiO30%3D).

It sounds like what you want to do is to create a link inside the admin to link over to the other platform. I've never used Joomla but I'v used WordPress a lot. WordPress admin files are located at `example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/file.php?action=action` and joomla at `example.com/joomla/adminstrator/index.php?option=option`

What I would suggest is to write a plugin that adds a [WordPress Admin Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) that will add links to the admin settings you need in Joomla.

The same thing for Joomla [create a module](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_module) that links back to WordPress admin.